# Bluetooth problem on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, 22.04, bluetooth

## Can't use bluetooth on my Ubuntu 22.04

I used a USB Bluetooth dongle on my PC, which can successfully work on Windows.  It always shows

> "searching for devices"

I have already checked:

```
inxi -Eaz
```

Its output is here:

```
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 1-1:2 chip-ID: 2b89:8761 class-ID: e001 serial: <filter>\
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.1 sub-v: 8761 hci-v: 5.1 rev: b\
  Info: acl-mtu: 1021:6 sco-mtu: 255:12
    link-policy: rswitch hold sniff park link-mode: peripheral accept
    service-classes: rendering, capturing, object transfer, audio, telephony
```

`lsusb` output here

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 25a7:fa7b Areson Technology Corp 2.4G Dual Mode Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2b89:8761 Realtek Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Edit to add results from terminal for `sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'`